# React: Passing HOC, to another HOC, gives element type invalid error

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass a HOC to another HOC, which is not working for me. Possibly some mistake I did

I have reduced my problem into following minimal working example:

I have an higher order component `B`:

```
export class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { InnerInB } = this.props;
    return (
      <InnerInB
        { 
          //pass props here
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

which we export as below:

```
export default InnerInB => props => <B { ...props } InnerInB={ InnerInB } />;
```

I have another higher order component `A` which takes another component `InnerComponent` in its props.

```
export const A = (props) => {
  const { InnerComponent} = props;

  return (
    <InnerComponent
// pass props here
     /> 
  );
};
```

and we export this higher component as `ExposedComponent`:

```
import InnerInB from './B';
const ExposedComponent = InnerComponent => (props) => {
  //Some code here...
  return (<A { ...props } InnerComponent={ InnerComponent } />);
};

export default ExposedComponent;

InnerInB(ExposedComponent);
```

I have another Higher order component `B`:

Now when I call `InnerInB(A)` inside the file where `A` is defined. This code however gives following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

However when I change `A` from higher order component to normal component, it works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a CodeSandbox or similar that reproduces this to make sure I'm not misunderstanding what is being called from where.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a React component must be a function or a class (per the error message), but in `A` you're returning neither—you're returning `<InnerComponent />`, which is a [component element](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-elements-vs-react-components/) (yes, the terminology is confusing):

```
export const A = (props) => {
  const { InnerComponent } = props;

  return (
    <InnerComponent
      // pass props here
    /> 
  );
};
```

You probably meant to do this instead:

```
export const A = (props) => {
  const { InnerComponent } = props;

  return () => (
    <InnerComponent
      // pass props here
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Jordan, this is a higher order component which by definition ```A higher-order component is a function that takes a component as an argument and returns a component```.

Comment: @RhythmWalia You're correct about the definition of a higher-order component—and by that same definition, your function is not a higher-order component. A component is a function or class, but your HoC returns `<InnerComponent/>`, which is neither a function nor a class.

Comment: Thank you! The distinction between return <Component /> and return () => <Component /> seems to appear nowhere else on the web.